# javascript, can I do this in a single declaration/line?

Tags: javascript

Sometimes I need a more complex object in JavaScript and I usually do something like this.

```
var myVar = ArrayWithMetaData(GetStringArray(),{description: "These are numbers", ...});

function ArrayWithMetaData(arr, params){
    var temp = params;
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        temp[i] = arr[i];
    return temp;
}

//TODO: Returns an array i.e. ["one", "two", "three"], may be very large 
function GetStringArray() {}
```

Is there a shorter method of accomplishing this or is there a library that provides similar functionality?

Also, is there a name for this type of javascript variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to define an object with straight json, where the array is one property, like:

```
var myVar = {"description": "These are numbers", "values": ["one", "two", "three"]};
```

Then you would just access the array using `myVar.values`.

Comment: *"Another option is to define an object with straight json..."* That's not JSON, that's a JavaScript object initializer; you don't use JSON directly in JavaScript code. JSON is a textual notation used *outside* source code (for instance, in data files or on-the-wire). If it *were* JSON, it would be invalid (and JSON requires that keys ["description" and "values"] be in double quotes).

Comment: fair enough - I added the quotes.

Comment: But the point is: It's not JSON. (Even with the quotes.) Calling it JSON is misleading. (Not in a big evil way, you understand; in a perpetuating-misunderstandings way.)

Comment: Not exactly what I was after but it fits nicely in one line. Thanks Mike.

Comment: TJ - According to [http://www.json.org/js.html], _"JSON is a subset of the object literal notation of JavaScript. Since JSON is a subset of JavaScript, it can be used in the language..."_ - json.org makes a distinction between a 'JSON text' (which I think is what you are referring to when you say JSON) and the object literal notation, which is what I am using above.  I don't know if you consider json.org authoritative - if you know of a better source of json info, please leave a link. Thanks :-)

Comment: Mike, http://json.org is authoritative -- that's Crockford's site, and Crockford defined JSON. You can write something sticking to the rules of JSON within JavaScript, yes. That doesn't make it JSON, it's still an object initializer (or an "object literal" as most people call it). There's no point in calling it JSON when it's not, or limiting the user to the subset of features (as soon as `description` comes from another variable, or any other value is calculated, you leave JSON behind). A barracks is a subset of an army base, but you wouldn't point to the base and call it a barracks.

Answer (score 6):

Well, you can do this:

```
var myVar = ["one", "two", "three"];
myVar.description = "These are numbers";
```

`Array` instances are objects just like anything else (in fact, in JavaScript, [arrays aren't really arrays](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html) at all), you can add arbitrary properties to them directly. If you do (and there are lots of use cases for it), just be sure that you don't use `for..in` incorrectly (see: [Myths and realities of `for..in`](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/11/myths-and-realities-of-forin.html)).

The above isn't exactly analogous to the result of your function, though, because your function's result isn't an `Array` anymore, whereas the above leaves the array as a real `Array` (so you can do all the things that only relate to the numeric properties — "indexes" — if you like). If you really want it not to be an `Array`, you could do this:

```
var myVar = {
    0: "one",
    1: "two",
    2: "three",
    description: "These are numbers"
};
```

That's an [*object initializer*](http://es5.github.com/#x11.1.5) (sometimes called an object literal).

Comment: Thanks for the info, however I was hoping for something a bit more generic. I'll update my question to reflect this.

Comment: @BiffMaGriff: Both of the above are fairly generic, aren't they? You're free to add arbitrary, non-index properties to any array; and you're free to add index-like properties to non-Array objects.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, the object that function returns is not an `Array` since you just copy each item of `arr` to a new property of `param`.  Instead, I'd do:

```
function ArrayWithMetaData(arr, params){
    for(var k in params)
        arr[k] = params[k];
    return arr;
}
```

This way you still have access to all of `Array`'s prototype methods, and `ArrayWithMetaData([],{}) instanceof Array == true`.